# How can I force other users to log out?

Tags: linux, user-management

Is there a simple way for me to force another user off of a linux box, while I am logged in as root?  I understand that I could determine what type of session they have open, and kill the pid - but I'm thinking there must be a command to do this that I don't know about.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can simply [`slay(1)`](http://packages.debian.org/slay) him. :-)

Comment: Ha! Neat. I'd never heard of this command before. Is it available on all systems? Sure looks like it beats killing their shell process.

Comment: It's probably packaged for all distros, but if you need something that works everywhere, skill from procps---as Mihai points out---might be a better choice. It has less style though ;-)

Comment: openSuse 11.4 - slay: command not found :( :(

Comment: Not installed on the Ubuntu 12.04 or RHEL 3 hosts that I have currently available, I do have the `skill` command detailed by Mihai Limbăşan. YMMV

Comment: Install it from universe: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=slay

Comment: @djechelon is right, and there is no package in the standard repositories that provides `slay`.  This is on openSUSE 12.3.

Answer (score 10):

You can kill all of an user's processes via `skill`. Example:

> - `skill -TERM -u username`

will send SIGTERM to all of `username`'s processes. To kill them for good (via SIGKILL) use -KILL instead of -TERM - please note, though, that you will most likely cause them to lose data that way. It's highly effective, mind you...

`skill` is part of the `procps` package which is installed by all distributions by default.

Comment: For others that want to do this for all remote user session, the -v flag (`-v pts/*`), which is from the man page might be useful.

Answer (score 3):

The `pkill` and `killall` are preferred over `skill`. This is from the `skill` man page:

> These tools are probably obsolete and unportable. The command syntax is poorly defined. Consider using the `killall`, `pkill`, and `pgrep` commands instead.

This should do the trick:

```
sudo pkill -KILL -u [user]
```

or

```
sudo killall -u [user]
```

Comment: [Don't try this on root.](http://serverfault.com/q/462512/126632)

Answer (score 0):

Another easy way to do it is to run `kill -1 <pid>` where **pid** is the process ID number of the SSH session.

By running this command, you can see all the **sshd** process trees, by killing the parent process ID you will effectively kill the user session associated with it:

```
$ ptree -p
```

Look for **sshd** and then run:

```
$ kill -1 39383
```

Where **39383** is an example of an arbitrary process ID number.